# How to add a external settings file in IIS configuration file

Tags: php, iis, iis-7

I want to create a project settings file (db_settings.inc) and put that file somewhere outside of document root folder and I need to include that file in the IIS configuration (applicationHost.config) file to access the settings values from settings file.

For this I am using PHP 5.3, IIS 7 and SQL server

Previously I have tried with Apache and works fine. But I am very new to IIS. So anyone can you please help in how to include the settings file in IIS config file? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating .inc file I have created it as .ini file and stored outside of document root folder. Now I am using `parse_ini_file` function to retrieve the settings data in an array format.

Hope this helps someone.